# Magento CSS merging

Tags: magento-1.7

I tried to merge the CSS in magento 1.7, All the files are updated in a single CSS file created in media/css_secure folder too, Still whole design is breaking.

Please sugeest what can be issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you have syntax error somewhere in your css.

You can copy whole merged css and validate your css in css validator and check which line causing the issue. because in css after error the rest of the css code wont work so validate your css .

You can use below listed css validator

https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

http://csslint.net/

http://codebeautify.org/cssvalidate

Or you can google it css validator and vaidate your css.

Comment: thanks for response.It was already solved by this way only :)

Comment: You are always welcome :)